# Failed to reach erlang port mapper (server ports open and connecting via Telnet)

Tags: azure, couchbase

I am trying to add a new server to an existing cluster. I am using community version 2.1.1 on both ubuntu servers on windows azure. I tried to add new server via web interface and via command line. But i am getting following error.

```
***"Failed to reach erlang port mapper. Timeout connecting to "xx.xx.xx.xx" on port "4369". This could be due to an incorrect host/port combination or a firewall in place between the servers.']***
```

**Port 4369 is open on both servers and iam able to connect to 4369 port on other server using telnet**

Got the same error when used the following command.

```
/opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-cli server-add --cluster=xx.xx.xx.xx:8091        -u user -p password       --server-add=yy.yy.yy.yy:8091        --server-add-username=Administrator   --server-add-password=password
ERROR: unable to server-add yy.yy.yy.yy:8091 (400) Bad Request
[u'Prepare join failed. Failed to reach erlang port mapper. Timeout connecting to "xx.xx.xx.xx" on port "4369".  This could be due to an incorrect host/port combination or a firewall in place between the servers.'] 

    root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/azureuser/project# telnet yy.yy.yy.yy 4369
    Trying yy.yy.yy.yy...
    Connected to yy.yy.yy.yy.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    ^]q


telnet> q
Connection closed.
```

What will be the issue? Please help me sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ports required to be open between cluster nodes (in addition to 4369) - I'd suggest ensuring all of the ports listed in the [Couchbase Installation Guide - Network ports](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-install/#network-ports) are open and accessible.